# rewriteRule for rewrite magento cms page to custom url

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have cretaed a cms page `https://example.com/page_url` in magento admin.

I want to create a rewriteRule in .htaccess file to rewrite cms page by custom url like `https://example.com/custom_url`.

For this I have created a rule as :

`RewriteRule ^custom_url /page_url [P]`

It is working on `http` server but not on `https` server.

What is the correct rule for rewrite `page_url` to `custom_url`?

Answer (score 1):

you can create url rewrite rules in the backend for this.
Go to Catalog->URL Rewrite management.
Add a new custom url rewrite, where the target it `page_url`, source is `custom_url`. Fill in a random id path and select a store id.

Comment: Hello @Marius, I have tried it, but it is not working for me and `https://example.com/page_url` also gives 404 error after that.